# Pause current video when close popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, html

I have a portfolio on my site.
when clicking on an item, it opens a popup modal with a video.

what I'm trying to do, is to pause the current video when close the modal.

So basically, I'm using this script to pause the video:

```
var vid = document.getElementById("video19"); 
$('#md-close').click(function(){
  vid.pause();
});
```

but  I have more than one video, and I can't use the same id for that.
I won't create a function for each video anytime.. its make the website slow and its bad.
 I tried to use getElementByClassName but it didn't work even in the last version of chrome.

So I just want one script that pauses the current video when I click on close button.

How can I do that?

Comment: You need a way to target whatever the "current video" is, and since that will be dynamic, you likely can't just target a class or ID unless you assign that class/ID to the video when you play it. Can you create a demo of what you have now? See how to create a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

Use a `class` instead of an `id` on your `video` tags.
Then... Use this to **pause them all !**

```
$('#md-close').click(function(){
  $(".yourClass").pause();       // Class used as a selector
});
```

Or without any `class` or `id`:

```
$('#md-close').click(function(){
  $("video").pause();       // Tag name used as a selector
});
```

Yes! Why pause a specific one when you can ensure all videos are paused?